how to compare Json response and UI elements with 2 arrays using for loop in selenium & rest assured automation
how to compare Json response and UI elements with 2 arrays using for loop in selenium &  rest assured automation.
We are comparing api response and ui responses.
I attached sample json overhere.
{
  "sports": [
    {
      "name": "basketball",
      "id": 40,
      "uid": "s:40",
      "leagues": [
        {
          "name": "National Basketball Assoc.",
          "abbreviation": "nba",
          "id": 46,
          "uid": "s:40~l:46",
          "groupId": 7,
          "shortName": "NBA",
          "athletes": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "resultsOffset": 10,
  "resultsLimit": 10,
  "resultsCount": 1,
  "timestamp": "2013-11-18T03:15:43Z",
  "status": "success"
}


Does this answer your question? Full Json match with RestAssured

Can you share some java code you've stuck with?
